# JavascriptExecutor gives error if driver is self.broswer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following piece of code in python.

```
def __init__(self, email, password):
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
```

Now when I am trying to add the following line

```
JavascriptExecutor js =((JavascriptExecutor) self.browser);
```

It is showing me invalid syntax. As far as I understand, it needs a driver. For me the driver is self.browser. Even after importing the library and also launching the page which I want to use, it still gives me error.
I don't want to change the way the driver is defined.

Comment: `JavascriptExecutor js =((JavascriptExecutor) self.browser);` this is the JAVA syntax, not python

Comment: Note: you need to run `pip install webdriver-manager` for `ChromeDriverManager().install()` to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use JAVA syntax on Python...

In Python, the JavascriptExecutor is in the driver...

Use:

```
self.browser.execute_script('your script')
```